# How to see the directory of a file in Intellij debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

This may apply across languages in intellij, though my example is about Java. I have a breakpoint at the line after this one:

`currentOut = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("tmp.output"));`

The variables tab shows:

[image: variables]

I have navigated down `charOut`, `out`, and `testOut` - nowhere is a path to file `tmp.output` shown. In the debugger, how can I see where this file got created?

Comment: Create a `File` object `f`. That should give you the path. If in doubt, assign `f.getAbsolutePath()` to a temporary variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in the current directory of the Application.
You can get it in the debugger by executing this inside evaluate expression box:

```
new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks!